# WD SATA Drive Showing Wrong Capacity

Tags: sata

I am stomped on this one.  Got a batch of 16 SATA drives.  They have the right label from WD, but also come with a sticker on them that's in an Asian language.  The drives are supposed to be 4TB, but everything I've done with them shows them as 5TB.  Here's the output of "smartctl -a" on one:

```
smartctl 6.2 2017-02-27 r4394 [x86_64-linux-3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Re
Device Model:     WDC WD4000FYYZ-01UL1B1
Serial Number:    WD-WMC1F1587O18
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 20c072a60
Firmware Version: 80.00A80
User Capacity:    5,000,981,078,016 bytes [5.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5700 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 3b
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 1.5 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Thu Apr  5 01:33:52 2018 CDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
```

Here's "parted" output:

```
[root@core mnt]# parted /dev/sdb print
Model: WDC WD40 00FYYZ-01UL1B1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 5001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  5001GB  5001GB
```

I have written known data to the whole disk via "dd" and then read it back.  It all checked out, down to the last byte.  I currently have 8 of them in a RAID6.  They built just fine with a capacity of 30005.88 GB and even do resync without an issue.  Everything I've done to these indicates that they're 5TB drives, but the firmware says otherwise.

Manufacturing mistake in labeling and applying wrong model numbers in firmware?  Cheap knockoffs?  They weren't particularly much cheaper than their usual price, maybe by a few bucks.

Comment: Accidents can happen.

Comment: 16TB for free, nice.

Comment: I thought perhaps that it was the difference between K=1000 vs K=1024, but that only 'brought the size down' to 4657-odd gigs each, still high for 4 teras.

Comment: I've yet to see a cheap knockoff of a hard drive - the tooling costs are way to high.  It could be remanufactured drives, but this looks to me like a firmware issue in your favour (A lot of different size drives are physically the same, but have different firmware to limit them and sell them for different prices - I speculate that this firmware update was wrong and mismatched the drive size and type).

Answer (score 1):

Manufacturing mistake in labeling and applying wrong model numbers in firmware? It's not unprecedented, and it can happen. Typically, these are isolated incidents. Just be glad you got some free TBs out of it.